# Distinct items of list order by their count in the list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of trees

```
   List<Tree> trees;
   ...
   filter_trees = trees.Distinct().ToList();
```

I want to select distinct trees, it works based on equality function of `Tree` class to distinguish distinct trees. Now I need to order these distinct trees based on their frequency (count) in the `trees`.

It may need a `group by` statement, however I prefer `Distinct` as it has no argument and works based on the specific `Equals` function I wrote.

Comment: Is it possible to see the equality function of yours? I believe you might adapt it to include the frequency.

Comment: Override *CompareTo()* too.

Comment: [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/) might have what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 4):

You can still do it all in one LINQ chain. GroupBy will respect your equality comparison, then you can select a complex item which contains both a tree and a count, then sort by the count, then pull out the tree.

```
var orderedTrees = trees
    .GroupBy(t => t)
    .Select(g => new
        {
            Tree = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count()
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => x.Tree)
    .ToList();
```